# How can different sites react to simple DOM manipulation?

Tags: javascript

I have a bookmarklet which sits in the browser bookmarks toolbar and when clicked simply alerts **foo** regardless of which site you're looking at (or it **should**)

The problem is, there are some sites where this doesn't happen, nothing does, why is this?

Bookmarklet code (to test add the following to your bookmarks toolbar)

```
javascript:(function(){Test=document.createElement('script');Test.src='http://example.com/js/test2.js';document.body.appendChild(Test);})();%20void(0);
```

test2.js is simply:

```
(function(){
  alert('foo');
 })();
```

For example, this works fine on **ebay.com**, when you click the bookmarklet an alert shows over the **ebay** page saying **foo**, but doesn't work on **pinterest.com**, nothing happens

Any ideas?

Comment: Anything in the console?

Comment: Could be related to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy.

Comment: pinterest.com does in fact implement the Content Security Policy, look in the Network tab of the developer tools and you will see the header being sent. Check the other sites you are trying this on to see if they do as well.

Comment: @tymeJV Nothing, even console.log('foo') instead of alert fails

Answer (score 0):

Many websites will not allow the addition of script elements to the page. Facebook is an example, bookmarklets that add a script tag to the DOM will not work on Facebook.